# ¿Contar numero de filas mediante la expresion en un reporte.rdlc?

Tags: mvc, report, rdlc

quisiera saber si existe la forma de contar el numero de filas de un reporte sin hacer consultas sql 
**trabajo en asp.net**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***tu solución***

```
= RowNumber(Nothing)
```